# Problem when sync user's picture to sharepoint 2013

Tags: picture, active-directory-import

I've make a People Directory. but the user's picture doesn't show up. But when I hover to user name this show the info with picture look like this. I dont know why. Someone can help me?
[image]

Comment: The hover picture is not actually part of SharePoint, it is created by an Active X control (I think that still is true for 2013) that fetches information from Lync

Comment: So, Do you have any ideas for this. User's picture doesn't show up

Comment: SharePoint needs some time to replication, it depends on how big is your farm, check it after a while?